# Python extracting values from sublist withing a column

Tags: python, pandas

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

I have a column in pandas data frame with the data type object. It has multiple lists within it. What I want to do is pick out the coordinates in terms of longitude and latitude and store them in a separate column. I've tried to create a new column with just coordinate values using: `df["A"]= df['geometry'].str[37:]`. I am not sure if the remaining values left are a set of multiple list or what.

```
geometry
0   {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-79.41469317817781, 43.6739104164259], [-79.41484930122832, 43.6743388247927], [-79.4155279126094, 43.67606998537741],..]]]}
```

Result should be

```
Longitudes                   Latitudes 

-79.41469317817781          43.6739104164259
-79.41484930122832          43.6743388247927
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try this. First save df as textfile first

```
with open('df.txt', 'r') as data:
  plaintext = data.read()

plaintext = plaintext.replace('-', '--')

#s = plaintext

plaintext = plaintext.replace("-", " ", 1)
#print(plaintext)
import re

start = '-'
end = '--'

a=(plaintext [plaintext .find(start)+len(start):plaintext .rfind(end)])
a = a.replace("[", "")
a = a.replace("]", "")
a = a.replace(",", "")
a = a.replace("--", "-")
print(a)
```

output

```
79.41469317817781 43.6739104164259 -79.41484930122832 43.6743388247927
```